# How can i pass multiple parameters in a single string in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

```
[{
    "SpatialFeatures": [1, "Polygon", "-0.7716963440179825 12.075162402107788,-0.7681990787386894 12.078687506101538,-0.7665897533297539 12.077910820042636,-0.7699797302484512 12.074763398853381,-0.7716963440179825 12.075162402107788", "03-10-2016 08:45:06 PM", "03-10-2016 08:47:58 PM", "359296058197964", null, "Burkina_Faso_Pilot", 291],
    "AttributeValue": [
        [
            [1, "1", "282", "41"],
            [1, "2", "45", "south123"],
            [1, "2", "46", "eaat123"],
            [1, "2", "44", "north123"],
            [1, "2", "16", "53"],
            [1, "2", "47", "west123"]
        ],
        [
            [1, "4", "1", "sonu1"],
            [1, "4", "2", "shukla1"],
            [1, "4", "264", "2016-11-03"],
            [1, "4", "4", "1"],
            [1, "4", "22", "3"],
            [1, "4", "270", "sultanpur"],
            [1, "4", "265", "testing"],
            [1, "4", "266", "ref id "],
            [1, "4", "267", "father"],
            [1, "4", "268", "mother"],
            [1, "4", "269", "122"],
            [1, "4", "271", "2016-11-03"],
            [1, "4", "5", "8010104086"]
        ],
        [
            [1, "3", "31", "129"]
        ],
        []
    ]
}]
```

Comment: what do you mean by "pasing multiple parameters in a single string"? what's the context of this question?

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

In [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) , select "Body Data" tab and don't forget to fill green surrounded fields at least:

[image]

You might want to use [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults).